# Picking correct N to prove convergence of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I am asked to show that:

lim $\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3}$=$0$. In other words, I need to show it converges to $0$.

Now, I have a general ideas about how the proof works,but I am just having more trouble picking my $N$.

Here is what I am doing, I was looking to rearrange the inequality $\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3}<\epsilon$ to leave the $n$ by it self, but I cannot seem to do it properly. I started by multiplying either side by $n^3+3$ then I divided by $\epsilon$ and finally I multiplied by 2. So I have $\frac{n^3+3}{n^2}>\frac{2}{\epsilon}$. Here is where I am not too sure how to continue so I can have n by itself because if I simplify the left hand side I get $n+\frac{3}{n^2}$.

Comment: Do you mean the limit as $n\to \infty$?

Comment: @Arthur I guess technically yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\left|
\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3}\right| < \left|
\frac{2n^2}{n^3}\right| < \left|
\frac{2}{n}\right| = \frac{2}{n} < \epsilon,
$$
therefore, 
$$
\frac{2}{n} < \epsilon \to \frac{2}{\epsilon} <n,
$$
namely, for every $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N =  [\frac{2}{\epsilon}]+1$, such that for every $n\ge N$, $\left| \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} \right|<\epsilon$.

Comment: I see, but how did you get this N?

Comment: Wait so what step am I missing in the last part of my inequality to get n by itself?

Comment: By a manipulating $2/n < \epsilon$

Comment: Instead of using the original $a_n$ to find the $n$, you should take slightly "larger" series in order to get more convenient expression of $n$ as a function of $\epsilon$.

Comment: I do not follow how the $\frac{3}{n^2}$ just goes away.

Comment: Because if the above inequality holds for $2n^2/n^3$, it also holds for the original series

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66308/discussion-between-sam-and-v-v).